# Escape double quoutes in c# SSIS script component send JSON from SQL data

Tags: c#, json, api

I have got hard to me problem. I got 1 column in SQL called [tag], this column got data like "Tag1\Tag1a","Tag2\Tag2b",... I need to send this to API, in API code it should look like that:

```
{
"contact": {
"email": "Row.email",
"name": "Row.name",
"externalId": "Row.exid",
"company": "Row.company",
"address": {
"streetAddress": "Row.strAdd",
"zipCode": "Row.code",
"city": "Row.city",
"country": "Row.country"
}
},
"owner": "Row.owner",
"properties": {
"someprop": "Row.someprop"
},
  "province": "Row.province",
  
  "dictionaryProperties": [{
  "name" : "nameOfProp",
  "type" : "NUMBER",
  "value": "Row.Value"
  }
],
"tags": [Row.tags],
"apiKey": "apikey",
"clientId": "cid",
"sha": "sha",
"requestTime": req.time,
"async": "true"
}
```

In c# I got string with data from InputBuffer, when I get data from Input to string I got error 400, I checked and this is becouse tags, how I can get this tags from input to string with this double quotes?

```
var data = "{ \"contact\": { \"email\": \"" + Row.email + "\", \"name\": \"" + Row.name + "\", \"externalId\": \"" + Row.exid.ToString() + "\", \"company\": \"" + Row.company + "\", \"address\": { \"streetAddress\": \"" + Row.strAdd + "\", \"zipCode\": \"" + Row.code + "\", \"city\": \"" + Row.city + "\", \"country\": \"" + Row.country + "\" } }, \"owner\": \"" + Row.owner + "\", \"properties\": { \"someProp\": \"" + Row.prop + "\" }, \"province\": \"" + Row.province + "\", \"dictionaryProperties\": " + Row.value + ", \"tags\": [" + Row.tags + "], \"apiKey\" : \"apikey\", \"clientId\": \"cid\", \"sha\": \"sha\", \"requestTime\": req.time, \"async\": \"true\" }";
```

1.I try to send empty [] from sql - doesnt work, but when I put it in code without get from input it worked
2.I try modify data in SQL column from "Tag1\Tag1a","Tag2\Tag2b" to "Tag1/Tag1a","Tag2/Tag2b" or ["Tag1/Tag1a","Tag2/Tag2b"]
3.I try add @to c# data - not work too.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a weird way of creating JSON data. Instead you could create the instruction with a bunch of classes and populate them with the data and serialize it into JSON format.

Comment: I was try classes, but I cant do same json like api required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change from unicode stream text to unicode text in Ole DB source and its worked!

Thanks for help